# Trying to set a variable from a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, setvalue

I'm learning python and am creating a rock paper scissors game.

I'm stuck on one part.

I have 4 variables currently (Although I would like to get it down to 2)

- pKey
- pChoice
- comKey
- comChoice

They look up the the Key and Value respectively in a dictionary.

```
choice = {1:'rock',  2:'paper',  3:'scissors'}
```

The problem I'm having is getting the keys from the dictionary using the variables.

Here's the code snippet that's giving me trouble

```
    print('--- 1 = Rock    2 = Paper     3 = Scissors --- ')
    pKey = input() # this is sets the key to the dictionary called choice
    while turn == 1: # this is the loop to make sure the player makes a valid choice
        if pKey == 1 or 2 or 3:
            pChoice = choice.values(pKey)  # this calls the value from choice dict and pKey variable
            break
        else:
            print('Please only user the numbers 1, 2 or 3 to choose')

    comKey = random.randint(1, 3)  # this sets the computer choices
    comChoice = choice.values(comKey)
```

Specifically the troublesome part is

```
 pChoice = choice.values(pKey)
```

and

```
 comChoice = choice.values(comKey)
```

I've tried everything I know from using brackets, trying different methods, and using different formats.

Would love to learn this! Thanks!

Comment: careful with `if pKey == 1 or 2 or 3`. It's not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that I would need to have it be    if pKey == 1 or pKey == 2 or pKey == 3:  is that on the right track?

Comment: You could do `if pKey == 1 or pKey == 2 or pKey == 3`, or you could do `if pKey in [1, 2, 3]`. However right now that will never be true, since `pKey` is `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're just trying to do a dictionary lookup

```
pKey = 1
pChoice = choices[pKey]  # rock
```

`dict.values` is used to create a list (actually a `dict_values` object) with all the values of the dictionary. It's not used as a lookup.

---

As far as your code structure goes, it could use some work. The rock/paper/scissors choice is perfect for an `Enum`, but that might be a bit beyond you right now. Let's just try as a toplevel module constant.

```
ROCK = "rock"
PAPER = "paper"
SCISSORS = "scissors"

def get_choice():
    """get_choice asks the user to choose rock, paper, or scissors and
    returns their selection (or None if the input is wrong).
    """
    selection = input("1. Rock\n2. Paper\n3. Scissors\n>> ")
    return {"1": ROCK, "2": PAPER, "3": SCISSORS}.get(selection)
```

Addressing them as constants makes sure they're the same everywhere in your code, or else you get a very clear NameError (instead of an if branch not executing because you did `if comChoice == "scisors"`)

---

A minimal example with an enum looks like:

```
from enum import Enum

Choices = Enum("Choices", "rock paper scissors")

def get_choice():
    selection = input(...)  # as above
    try:
        return Choices(int(selection))
    except ValueError:
        # user entered the wrong value
        return None
```

You could extend this by using the more verbose definition of the Enum and teach each Choice instance how to calculate the winner:

```
class Choices(Enum):
    rock = ("paper", "scissors")
    paper = ("scissors", "rock")
    scissors = ("rock", "paper")

    def __init__(self, loses, beats):
        self._loses = loses
        self._beats = beats

    @property
    def loses(self):
        return self.__class__[self._loses]

    @property
    def beats(self):
        return self.__class__[self._beats]

    def wins_against(self, other):
        return {self: 0, self.beats: 1, self.loses: -1}[other]

s, p, r = Choices["scissors"], Choices["paper"], Choices["rock"]
s.wins_against(p)  # 1
s.wins_against(s)  # 0
s.wins_against(r)  # -1
```

Unfortunately there's no great way to lose the abstraction in that (abstracting out "paper" to Choices.paper every time it's called) since you don't know what `Choices["paper"]` is when `Choices.rock` gets instantiated.

Comment: I haven't come across the `Enum` portion of the book I'm working in yet, but this does look a lot cleaner and easier to read. I'll look it up. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the idea how to take element from dict, your code should be like this:

```
import random
choice = {1: 'rock',  2: 'paper',  3: 'scissors'}

print('1 = Rock\t2 = Paper\t3 = Scissors')
pKey = int(input())
if pKey in (1, 2, 3):
    pChoice = choice[pKey]
else:
    print('Please only user the numbers 1, 2 or 3 to choose')
    pChoice = 'No choice'

comKey = random.randint(1, 3)
comChoice = choice[comKey]
print(pChoice, comChoice)
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: please change `if pkey == 1 or 2 or 3` to something that actually works, such as `int(pkey) in [1,2,3]`. currently, it will be read as `if (pkey == 1) or (2) or (3)` which will always assert to `True`

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask since i'm new, why does it need to be changed to an Int before it works?  pChoice = choice[int(pKey)]  Does it read the pKey as a string even though it's a number?

Comment: @EddieFlores Yes, you always get string from the `input()`